# How do you use amcharts4 to drilldown on Column Chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I currently have a working implementation of a column chart via amcharts4.  There is currently well documented support to drill down on a column chart using amcharts3 (https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6d37617fa24f57037b9f382e889ade4f), but the guidance to perform similar functionality in amcharts4 is poor.  I'm looking for assistance to drill down on a column chart using amcharts4.  The chart is currently rendering, but I'm having issues with my event listener below and I need help. My amchart4 column chart can be found at (https://jsfiddle.net/x8vrftak/) and the below code needs to fixed so the chart performs exactly like ((https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6d37617fa24f57037b9f382e889ade4f) once a column is clicked

Javascript Code That needs attention
(Event Listener): (https://jsfiddle.net/x8vrftak/)

```
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data =

   [
       {
  "category": 2009,
  "income": 23.5,
  "url": "#",
  "description": "click to drill-down",
  "months": [{
    "category": 1,
    "income": 1
  }, {
    "category": 2,
    "income": 2
  }, {
    "category": 3,
    "income": 1
  }, {
    "category": 4,
    "income": 3}
    ]

}, {
  "category": 2010,
  "income": 26.2,
  "url": "#",
  "description": "click to drill-down",
  "months": [{
    "category": 1,
    "income": 4
  }, {
    "category": 2,
    "income": 3
  }, {
    "category": 3,
    "income": 1
  }, {
    "category": 4,
    "income": 4
  }]
}, {
  "category": 2011,
  "income": 30.1,
  "url": "#",
  "description": "click to drill-down",
  "months": [{
    "category": 1,
    "income": 2
  }, {
    "category": 2,
    "income": 3
  }, {
    "category": 3,
    "income": 1
  }]
}];



// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "income";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series.name = "Income";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;


series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    if('object' === typeof ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months){

        // set the monthly data for the clicked month
         ev.chart.data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months

        // update the chart title
        ev.chart.titles[0].text = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.category + ' monthly data';


    }

 //console.log("clicked on ", ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.category);



}, this);



}); // end am4core.ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the chart object through the event target's [baseSprite](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/sprite/#baseSprite_property) and update the chart from there. Titles are stored in the chart's [`titles`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#titles_property) list object, which you first need to create prior to the event and then access it through [`getIndex`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#getIndex_method).

```
  var title = chart.titles.create();
  title.text = "Yearly Data";
  // ...
  series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    if ('object' === typeof ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months) {
      // update the chart title
      ev.target.baseSprite.titles.getIndex(0).text = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.category + ' monthly data';
      // set the monthly data for the clicked month
      ev.target.baseSprite.data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months

    }
  }, this);
```

If you need the reset label, create one on the plot container and set a `hit` event to reset the data back to the base state:

```
  var resetLabel = chart.plotContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
  resetLabel.text = "[bold]<< Back to Yearly Data[/]";
  resetLabel.x = 35;
  resetLabel.y = 20;
  resetLabel.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;
  resetLabel.hide(); //hide by default until drill down occurs
  resetLabel.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
    resetLabel.hide();
    ev.target.baseSprite.titles.getIndex(0).text = "Yearly Data";
    ev.target.baseSprite.data = chartData;
  });
  // ...
  series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    if ('object' === typeof ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months) {
      // ...
      // toggle the label on when drill down occurs
      resetLabel.show();
    }
  }, this);
```

Demo below:

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  // Themes end

  // Create chart instance
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  var chartData = [{
    "category": 2009,
    "income": 23.5,
    "url": "#",
    "description": "click to drill-down",
    "months": [{
      "category": 1,
      "income": 1
    }, {
      "category": 2,
      "income": 2
    }, {
      "category": 3,
      "income": 1
    }, {
      "category": 4,
      "income": 3
    }]

  }, {
    "category": 2010,
    "income": 26.2,
    "url": "#",
    "description": "click to drill-down",
    "months": [{
      "category": 1,
      "income": 4
    }, {
      "category": 2,
      "income": 3
    }, {
      "category": 3,
      "income": 1
    }, {
      "category": 4,
      "income": 4
    }]
  }, {
    "category": 2011,
    "income": 30.1,
    "url": "#",
    "description": "click to drill-down",
    "months": [{
      "category": 1,
      "income": 2
    }, {
      "category": 2,
      "income": 3
    }, {
      "category": 3,
      "income": 1
    }]
  }];

  chart.data = chartData;

  // Create axes

  var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
  categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#";

  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
    if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
      return dy + 25;
    }
    return dy;
  });

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = "income";
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series.name = "Income";
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
  series.columns.template.propertyFields.url = "url"; 
  

  var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
  columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
  columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

  var title = chart.titles.create();
  title.text = "Yearly Data";
  var resetLabel = chart.plotContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
  resetLabel.text = "[bold]<< Back to Yearly Data[/]";
  resetLabel.x = 20;
  resetLabel.y = 20;
  resetLabel.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;
  resetLabel.hide();
  resetLabel.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
    resetLabel.hide();
    ev.target.baseSprite.titles.getIndex(0).text = "Yearly Data";
    ev.target.baseSprite.data = chartData;
  });

  series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    if ('object' === typeof ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months) {
      // update the chart title
      ev.target.baseSprite.titles.getIndex(0).text = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.category + ' monthly data';
      // set the monthly data for the clicked month
      ev.target.baseSprite.data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.months
      resetLabel.show();
    }
  }, this);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```